Output Capacitor RMS current
The output capacitor used in the phase shift full bridge converter has RMS current calculation in the Texas document. Calculation is given below:

Source: https://www.lcsc.com/datasheet/lcsc_datasheet_Texas-Instruments-TI-UCC28950PWR_C91312.pdf
Converter Vout= 12 V, Pout=600 W, Iout = 50 A.
ΔILout is calculated as 10 A in the datasheet.
The point that I didn't understand is if the Iout = 50 A, I didn't understand the meaning of 5.8 A of RMS current?
Here is the additional information regarding the converter:

Source: https://www.lcsc.com/datasheet/lcsc_datasheet_Texas-Instruments-TI-UCC28950PWR_C91312.pdf

Source: https://www.lcsc.com/datasheet/lcsc_datasheet_Texas-Instruments-TI-UCC28950PWR_C91312.pdf

Have you tried to simulate or hand-calculate the current waveform?

Remember that a capacitor doesn't carry DC current - it's basically a filter to minimize the ripple at the output.
Therefor when the inductor carries a current which is a sim of a DC load current plus (triangular) ripple current, basically the DC part (10 A) passes though the load , while the AC part passes through the capacitor (and has no DC component of current.

The calc is totally reasonable .They give delta I of 10 amps which is 20% of the  load DC current of 50 amps .This is a reasonable figure to give good control and  not too large output choke .The Delta I or the AC componant of the choke current waveform is a very good approximation to a triangle wave if the choke is well away from saturation and has low DCR .The standard formulae for triangle wave rms current has square root 3 .The RMS current is important when capacitor heating due to esr is considered .You can select your output caps with a total rms current rating of more than 5.8amps.

Okay it is reasonable but my point is if I am drawing 50A from the output, when this 5.8A of rms current takes place. @Autistic


The point that I didn't understand is if the Iout = 50 A, I didn't
understand the meaning of 5.8 A of RMS current?

The 5.8 amps RMS is the ripple current through the capacitor and has little to do with the 50 amps DC output current of the power supply. Remember that the output capacitor is smoothing the output voltage hence, there has to be ripple current through that capacitor.
